# Can a mathematical operator be used in a switch expression?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm having a problem using a mathematical operator in a switch expression.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
var x = 18;
var y = 82;

var result = x + y;

switch(result) {
case "200":
document.write("200!");
break;
case "500":
document.write("500!");
break;
case "100":
document.write("100! :)");
break;
default:
document.write("Something's not right..");
}
```

**Explained**: the variable "result" has a value of 100. I am trying to use that value with the switch operator, but it just isn't working.

I've also tried using the equation itself as the switch expression, but that doesn't work either.

**P.S**: I just started out with JavaScript. Bet I missed something obvious...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change "100" to 100 and it works.  switch must be using the semantics of `===`  which means 'type and value are equal' vs `==`, which will try to make the types similar and then compare.

EDIT -- here is a screenshot showing it working

[image]

Comment: I know it is working. I was working on a different version of the script locally. My bad :)

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing the number `100` to the string `"100"`, that isn't the same. Try this:

```
var x = 18;
var y = 82;

var result = x + y;

switch(result) {
case 200:
document.write("200!");
break;
case 500:
document.write("500!");
break;
case 100:
document.write("100! :)");
break;
default:
document.write("Something's not right..");
}
```

Comment: @Sweely: I just validated this answer in Safari and it indeed outputs "100! :)". You must be doing doing something strange that you're not showing us.

Answer (score 3):

You are using strings in your case statements.  Take the quotes (`"`) out and you should be fine.